# Cannot open local HTML files with Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I am trying to open a local HTML file but I get an error every time that I do. The error message is as follow:

Error: Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item

I have checked the properties of the file and I do have access to everything about it and I have tried other HTML files too. These files open perfectly on Microsoft edge and internet explorer, but not with Chrome. I have updated, repaired and reinstalled google chrome but to no avail. I remember a while back I was tinkering with RegEdit so that may be the issue? I am not 100% sure though as I was not editing Google Chrome files.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to open the files? RIght click and "open with" ? Just double click due to file type association? Are you typing in a file path to the URL bar manually?  This is something that should Just Work (unless maybe there are dynamic includes, etc. but for a simple static HTML file it should just work)

Answer (score 2):

## Easy way:

1. Create a new shortcut for `chrome.exe`.
2. Right click > Properties
3. Change `Target` from `"c:\path\to\chrome.exe"` to `"c:\path\to\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-file`. Click OK to save.
4. Run chrome using this shortcut
5. Drag & drop html files to open.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode

## Easier way:

- If you have `python` installed, run cmd, change directory to your folder, run `python -m http.server`
- Or download [Caddy server](https://caddyserver.com/download), run `caddy -port 80`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a million. Weird how it wont work normally.. thanks again!

Comment: It's a security measure to prevent malicious website from reading files on your PC, that's why it's hidden behind a flag.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I did not expect to find answer for this specific problem.